# Force flush of Rocksdb memory table to disk

Tags: rocksdb

In RocksDB writes are stored in an in-memory buffer namely `memtable`. The memtable gets flushed into disk (`SSTable` sorted static table) once it gets full. Is it possible to programmatically  ***enforce*** flushing the memtable to disk before its gets full?  What Rocksdb APIs does it if any?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

DB::Flush() is the function to use: https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/6.23.fb/include/rocksdb/db.h#L1264-L1282